# Add weights to .pb file exported by TensorFlow

Tags: android, python, neural-network, tensorflow

My project uses Python to train a MLP on TensorFlow and then I export the graph and the weights in that way:

```
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, "./", "inp.txt", True) 
saver.save(sess, 'variables/model.ckpt', global_step=1)
```

Now, although it is fine to use both files to import it back to Python it seems impossible to use it for Android or C++ since it cannot inport the checkpoint .ckpt.

Right now, I'm using the script `freeze_graph.py` provided by google to join both files into one by doing:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph --input_graph=inp.txt --input_checkpoint=variables/model.ckpt-1 --output_graph=newoutput.pb --output_node_names=output
```

My question is, is there a way to use another function instead of `tf.train.write_graph` to export it with the weights included?

Comment: There are various ways to export a TensorFlow model for inference on Android (or from C++) but they tend to use the same techniques as `freeze_graph.py`, and they tend to work on `GraphDef` protobufs written by a function like `tf.train.write_graph()`. To help answer the question, can you clarify why `tf.train.write_graph()` and `freeze_graph.py` don't work for you?

Comment: Well, there are several reasons for that. I belive that the most important is that you can't really use freeze_graph unless you've installed it from source. Another problem is to have many files being generated. There is also the problem related to optimus laptops where freeze_graph requires the videocard to be disabled on a specific state to work, sometimes requiring a full restart.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I'm sorry to tell there is no way.

As discussed previously on Github ([have a look](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5481)), TensorFlow team does not currently address this problem.

Can't say anything for now.

`pltrdy`

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to do that, unfortunately.

It would be really good to have a way to do that directly. I mean, it would be great to have something to do it a single shot way instead of having to generate two files and then run another script to convert those.

It is specially bad for those who use hybrid graphics on a laptop.

Anyways, as TensorFlow group said:

> We do not have plans to support outputting .pb files directly. If you
>   are worried about too many checkpoint files taking up space, you can
>   limit the max_to_keep to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, freezegraph is the only way to address this issue.

For me it doesn't work quite well because I have to install it on many computers daily since people keep messsing things up and freezegraph forces me to install it from source.

They have to create another way to do it. A built-in way. Specially if they want us to use to for android.